# Redeclaration of the exception parameter

Tags: c++, declaration, language-lawyer

In the program we can redeclare an exception parameter as well as a function parameter like this:

```
#include <exception>

void foo()
try
{ 
    throw *new std::exception(); 
}
catch (std::exception e) 
{
    extern int e;
}
int main(){ foo(); }
```

But the standard forbids to do that `N4296:3.3.3/3 [basic.scope.block]`:

> The name declared in an exception-declaration is local to the handler
>   and *shall not be redeclared* in the outermost block of the handler.

We can't redefine the entity denoted by the exception parameter, but can redeclare one. Is it exactly what the Standard means in that rule?

Comment: Is it relevant to your question that you are throwing a copy of a `new` exception and leak the original?  This disturbs me a little.

Comment: The standard says "shall not be redeclared" and you are asking if it actually means "can be redeclared, but not redefined"? My guess is that you are wrong and the standard means exactly what it says.

Comment: Also, please fix your code.

Comment: @5gon12eder What's the right way to do it in c++? Is [**it**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85ede9c069ee93fe) considered correct?

Comment: @DDrmmr Yes, but as you can see I redaclared one within the handler, but no redefined.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv The general rule is: **`throw` by value – `catch` by `const` refrence.**  There might be cases where you have good reasons to do otherwise but if you don't, this will work best.  The code in your link `catch`es by value which introduces the problem of slicing (and makes an additional copy).

Comment: @5gon12eder Not to mention the fact that it leaks the `new`-ed instance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard means precisely what it says. A program which redeclares the name used in the *exception-declaration* (`e` in your case) in the outermost block of the *compound-statement* of the *handler* is ill-formed, since it violates a "shall" rule (the very one you quote). If your compiler accepts it silently, it's a bug in the compiler. If it accepts it with a warning, it could be a bug or an extension.